# Cómo llamar a la funcion de un script desde otro script en python?

Tags: python, funciones, modular

Tengo un script llamado `module_get.py` que se encarga mediante el uso de una función `get()` de ir a un archivo de texto y obtener el valor numérico asociado a los parametros pasados al `get()`.

Este sería el script `module_get.py` que contiene el get en cuestión:

```
import sys
#Take parameters of a plain text (file parameters.txt)

def get(rule_name,parameter_name):
    try:
        with open("parameters.txt", "r") as infile:   
            for line in infile:
                frame = line.split(":")
                if line.startswith(rule_name.lower()) and frame[1] == parameter_name.lower():
                    return check_len(frame) #comprova longitud i retorna el valor
    except Exception: #No such file or directory si no se encentra el archivo
        raise NameError("Doesnt exist the .txt especified")


def check_len(frames):
    if len(frames) == 3:
        return frames[2]
    elif len(frames) < 3 or len(frames) > 3:
        raise Exception("Wrong format in parameter required")

if __name__=="__main__":
    try:
        print(get("metadata","THR1")) #Este seria el formato de la llamada
    except TypeError:
        raise Exception("Invalid get format, missing rule or parameter (or both)") #en caso de no pasar una regla o parametro o introducir parametros adicionales
```

¿Como puedo crear un script llamado `module.py` que se encargue de llamar a la función `get()` de `module_get.py` y me retorne el valor asociado?

El archivo de texto `parameters.txt` presenta la siguiente estructura:

```
metadata:thr1:1
metadata:thr2:2
metadata:thr3:3
metadata:thr4:4
metadata:thr5:5
```

Comment: `from module_get import get` Y después `get(parametros, apropiados)`. Para que funcione, `module_get.py` debe estar en la misma carpeta que el script que lo importa, o bien debe estar instalado correctamente en la ruta donde Python busca los módulos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estoy de acuerdo con el comentario de abulafia, en el caso de estar en la misma carpeta:

en models.py:

```
from .model_get import get
```

El . indica que models.py y model_get.py se encuentran en la misma ruta